# Migrate data from old MySQL schema to a new schema

Tags: php, mysql, database-migration

I am trying to figure out the best approach to migrating data from an old database schema to that of a new schema. Basically I am dealing with a software replacement (thus new database structures) and now I need to migrate the data from the old database into the new one. Unfortunately this will not be as easy as running a simple insert into query based on a select from the old schema.

Example structure of what I could find in the *old schema*:

** Courses **

```
| id | title               | start_date | price  |
| 1  | Some course title 1 | 2019-10-09 | 100.00 |
| 2  | Some course title 2 | 2019-10-09 | 100.00 |
```

Of course the real table has many more columns, but this is just to give a basic idea.

In the new schema the structure is such that two tables exist, one of which holds translated values for the course title's.

Example structure of what I could find in the *new schema*:

** Courses **

```
| id | title_tid | start_date | price  |
| 1  | 1         | 2019-10-09 | 100.00 |
| 2  | 2         | 2019-10-09 | 100.00 |
```

** Translations **

```
| id | content_en          | content_nl |
| 1  | Some course title 1 | null       |
| 2  | Some course title 2 | null       |
```

In the new schema this allows us to have the user translate their course title to multiple languages, etc. The translations table is also used by many other sources in the new schema.

The basis of my problem is that I would have to, or at least think I have to, loop through the records of the old schema's Courses table and for each record first create a Translations record in the new schema. From that translation I require the ID to put in title_tid of the new Courses table.

Now, what is the best way to go about this? Can I do this purely in SQL or would it require me to write a script to migrate this data? For example in PHP or something like that? This wouldn't of course be very good for performance.

Edit:
Yes, I am aware that this translate setup is extremely poor in design and I have no idea why these guys went with this... but hey, not the point here :P

Comment: You can do this in sql or any other programming language. In case of a migration, performance is not particularly important - it is a one-off exercise.

Comment: Would you know how to go about this in SQL itself? I could do it perfectly in PHP really, but my skill in SQL is falling short.

Comment: Then do it in php because if you cannot do this in sql, then you will have problems performing other transformations as well. It is better to use the same technology for the entire migration process.

Comment: Technically correct of course, but I am looking to learn something new here in the process as well :) Like I said, I can do it in PHP just fine, but that isn't necessarily the best way to go about it. Especially when considering that the real database I am working with contains north of a 100 tables and millions of records. It is not really doable to just sit around waiting for a few hours each time I want to test this because PHP is so slow looping through this stuff all the time :)

Comment: With such large database, the transformation will take a lot of time and will likely to get it wrong a couple of times. Pls do not expect this to be done completely in a couple of hours. Accuracy here is a lot more important than a couple of extra hours or even days. This task here really requires basic SQL ( copy titles to the new titles table, then copy courses into the new courses table using a join between titles and courses table to get the title id).

Comment: If you have a problem with this, then either do the migration in a language you are comfortable with, or hire somebody who have done db migrations before and knows sql.